# Adjust a disk space available for a directory in Linux

Tags: directory, lvm, disk, resize2fs

I need to adjust the disk space given for an ordinary directory such as /opt directory. I'd found that the /opt directory allocates the space **4.0G**, by using the below command:

```
sudo du -sh /opt
```

I need to increase the disk space given for /opt directory up to **5.0G**. I saw that `lvm` or `resizef2s` could be used for the files system. Could be there an easier way to solve the issue I had?

Note: My Linux instance is installed on Vbox with a 40.0G disk space.

Please don't vote my question down because I am stuck in this issue for three days and I can't find a solution. Any comment might help.

Comment: `du` shows size of the directory, if it shows 4 GiB for `/opt` it doesn't mean it is limited to 4 GiB. Please update your question with output of `df -h` (this shows actual sizes and available space for all filesystems) and also `lsblk` (this will help us with the resizing part, if needed).

Comment: @VojtechTrefny Thanks for your comment. I'll update my question

Comment: Directories do not of themselves have sizes. The partition containing the file system has the fixed size. My output from `df -h /opt` is `/dev/sda7  20G   14G  5.4G  71% /` where `sda7` is the partition and `/` is the root partition, which (in my install) contains /bin, /dev, /etc, /lib, /opt, /tmp, /usr, /var. You might create /opt on another file system and mount it through a link.

Comment: the OP got stuck yet doesn't respond to any comment, so this question should be deleted

Answer (score 1):

The command you've mentioned shows the amount of the storage space which is occupied by all files inside the directory `/opt` not the size of its partition. For that you should do `df -h`. See if there is a separate partition even mounted on `/opt`.

Comment: You can `df -h /opt` and the filesystem that contains `/opt` will be measured and displayed